# Denormalizing / projecting data in CQRS

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm looking into CQRS (and DDD in general) and I'm not sure how to implement a particular part of it.

I understand the benefits of separating commands and queries; let's say for the sake of it that I'm also using event sourcing and I have a nice list of the history for each of my entities.

As I understand it, the data-storage my views will be built from can be in any form, and it's quite acceptable to denormalise this for performance.

My question is how to implement the transformation / projection from my normalised/event-centric write DB to my view-ready / denormalised tables?

Do I implement this with events from my domain model, listened to by another part of the application? Do I use SQL views (this wouldn't work using RDBMS/NoSQL mix).

How to do this without polluting the domain model with various unnecessary getters?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track using your domain events to manage read projections. Your aggregates does not need to expose their internal state as the domain events broadcasted by them would contain all necessary information to update your view projections. The view projection data can then be stored in any form.

For implementation details, take a look at [Greg Youngs CQRS example](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r), in particular the [domain implementation](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/Domain.cs) and the [read model implementation](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/ReadModel.cs).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Seems like there's lots of View objects which subscribe to the Domain events and know how to update their storage. What does seem worrying is that if you're doing this without ES, you're building your view data from event history which is lost as soon as the original entity is saved - makes that hard to rebuild.

Comment: Yes, without ES you might need to expose more internals of your aggregates, or you could use the domain events as a general indication of change and query the data source(s) of your aggregates directly.